# Composing the POST Http request to Add a Google Calendar API v3 Event

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add an event to Google Calendar from within a test console app.
I have a token_refresh obtained for the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" via a web application that I registered at the Google API Console.
I use this stored token_refresh in my test console app to get an access_token.
Then I want to add an event to the calendar of the user that corresponds to the refresh_token that I have.

So I build a POST HttpWebRequest as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + calendarID + "/events") as HttpWebRequest; // Where calendarID is like joe@gmail.com
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
request.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Method = "POST"; 

GoogleCalendarEvent anEvent = new GoogleCalendarEvent();
anEvent.start = new GoogleCalendarEventTime(DateTime.Today);
anEvent.end = new GoogleCalendarEventTime(DateTime.Today);            

string data = jsonSerializer.Serialize(anEvent); // jsonSerializer is a JavaScriptSerializer object
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
Stream ws = request.GetRequestStream();
ws.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
ws.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // throws WebException The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string result = stream.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

And the helper classes are:

```
private class GoogleCalendar
{
    private string kind;
    private string etag;
    private string id;
    private string summary;
    private string timezone;
    private string accesrole;

    public string Kind 
    { 
      get {  return this.kind;}
      set { this.kind = value; }
    }

    public string Etag 
    {
       get { return this.etag; }
       set { this.etag = value; }             
    }

    public string ID 
    {
       get { return this.id; }
       set { this.id = value; } 
    }

    public string Summary 
    {
       get { return this.summary; }
       set { this.summary = value; }
    }

    public string TimeZone 
    {
       get { return this.timezone; }
       set { this.timezone = value; }
    }

    public string AccessRole 
    {
       get { return this.accesrole; }
       set { this.accesrole = value; } 
    }
}

private class GoogleCalendarEventTime
{
    private DateTime _date;

    public string date
    {
        get
        {
            return this._date.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
        }
    }

     public GoogleCalendarEventTime(DateTime time)
     {
         this._date = time;
     }
}
```

My problem is that when the I try to get a response for the request I get an Error 400 Bad request. This type of error code is for both when a POST is badly constructed and as a placeholder for unknown errors.

Comment: Please tell me how can I generate the access_token @alexnaicu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google provides a [client library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/), which will make this much easier for you. An explanation of how to configure the client library with the Calendar API is available [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate) (click the .NET tab on that page).

This line constructs the service object which you will use to make API calls:

```
var service = new CalendarService();
```

Unfortunately, there aren't comprehensive samples for using .NET with all of the API methods of the Calendar API, but you can see a [list](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs) of all the APIs supported by this client library, many of which have examples. The usage pattern will be nearly identical across the APIs.

Comment: Please tell me how can I generate the access_token and One More what is the difference bw Google API's and SDK.@Dan Holevoet